# rails logger not running as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, puma, vnc, tightvnc

A legacy application (rails 4.2.10) was uploaded for staging purposes to a new server.

The log was populating at the start, but it all stopped at a certain point.  Having to load a large database from google cloud, a browser was necessary as the link is to a page, not the object to download. VNC was installed, the file accessed and downloaded and VNC uninstalled shortly thereafter.

The last log entries are for malicious actors hitting the server targetting wordpress pages. wordpress is not installed.  I cannot ascertain when they correspond to VNC installation/deactivation.

But no application page hits are registered past that point in time (quite a few days).

NGINX is the web server with the passenger nginx library. In development mode, puma 4.3.5 is invoked.

Is there any way to kickstart the Rails logger?

Comment: How is your app being run? This may influence the logging (e.g. passenger via nginx or apache2, a puma process started directly, or various processes started through a Procfile...)

Comment: ahh... yes nginx is the server, but puma is called in the development environment.  Question updated.

Comment: Maybe the logs are in a different location? Is the logging working correctly on local? And have there been any changes in the logging configuration?

Comment: The logs are working in local, yes.  The only thing I attempted was to add to `config/environments/development.rb` the `config.log_level = :debug` configuration

Comment: Good pickup @TheGeorgeous .  `/releases/20201104135429/log/development.log` was pickedup by Ubuntu and *has* the entries of hits to the application.  So it appears the symlink si somehow broken.